# primes of the form $ 2^p +q $ where p and q are primes

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

i am looking some refernce or texttes about prime numbers of the form

$$ p =2^{q}+r $$

where all $p,q,r $ are prime numbers

there are several examples $ 11= 2^3+3 $ , or $ 2^{4}+7 =23 $

Comment: In your second example, $4$ is not prime :P, looks interesting though

Comment: $7 = 2^2 + 3$ a better example? I suppose you may want to look at books on the twin prime conjecture first since that is the same problem with $q = 1$

Comment: Yes, there are several of these.  See [OEIS A013597](https://oeis.org/A013597) for entries that are prime.

Comment: Similar question asked on mathoverflow: [prime plus a power of 2?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49786/form-of-primesprime-plus-a-power-of-2)

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is a [dual Sierpinski number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number#Dual_Sierpinski_problem), for example $r = 271129$ which is also prime, then there are no solutions to $p = 2^q + r$ with prime $p$.  There is no value of $r$ that is known to have an infinite number of solutions.

The [k-tuple conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjecture) implies that there are an infinite number of prime solutions $(p, r)$ for any fixed $q \gt 0$.  But it seems like [Zhang's theorem and related results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#Other_theorems_weaker_than_the_twin_prime_conjecture) do not help us show that there exists even one such $q$.

Is it possible to prove there are an infinite number of satisfying triples?